# Directive that calls a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am considering making an angular directive that calls an angular service for retrieving data. I know it is generally bad practice to bind a model object (service in this case) to a UI element (directive) but I am not sure of a better way to accomplish what I am doing.

My app has sessions and transactions with a one-to-many relationship. Throughout the user interface, I need to show logs that were generated, and I have littered my UI with repetitive code for retrieving and displaying the log section. I was thinking about creating a directive to handle this, but it would have to hit my API to get the logs.

The directive might look like:

```
<customLogs identifier="transaction.TransactionId" 
            identifierType="transaction" />
```

Is there a better way of solving this that doesn't involve having a directive that ultimately hits my API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
module.directive( "addBookButton", [ 'Book', function( Book ) {
  return {
     restrict: "A",
     link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
       element.bind( "click", function() {
          Book.addBook( { title: "Star Wars", author: "George Lucas" } );
        });
     }
   }
 }]);
```

[See this Model Page](http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/)

Comment: The problem isn't injecting a service into a directive. The problem I am having is coming up with a way to simplify the display of the same information across multiple places without breaking the MV* pattern by connecting my model directly to my view.